# Domain of definition of antiderivative of $1/\sin z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Short question: On which domain does $1/\sin z$ have an antiderivative?

I would assume that I can take any disk $D_r(p)$ with $D_r(p)\cap \pi\mathbb Z=\emptyset$ since every closed integral should be zero according to the residue theorem. But in the solutions of my problem sheet it says that there is no such domain. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $D$ is a simply connected domain, which contains no zero of $\sin$, then $1/\sin z$ has an antiderivative on $D$.